# Django templates rendering issue

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django, trying my hand at creating a web app based on the self learn tutorial. i have created a app with name "travello" and project name is "travellproject", in the views i'am trying to render a html page.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'homepage.html')
```

i have created the "templates" directory under travellproj (please refer the directory structure below) also defined DIRS of template variable as below and urls.py as below.

```
"DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.homepage),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

But I'm receiving a TemplateDoesNotExist error, please help.

**Error**

TemplateDoesNotExist at /
homepage.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
homepage.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\Django\first_proj\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  travello.views.homepage

Directory structure:

```
travello
|-views.py
travellProj
|-templates -- > homepage.html
|-urls.py
|-setting.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Your templates folder should be at the root of your site. Let see how it should look like:

```
Project_folder
|-travelproj <-- Your site configuration folder
|-|-urls.py
|-|-wsgi.py
|-|-asgi.py
|-|-.......
|-travello <-- this is an application
|-|-views.py
|-|-urls.py
|-|-templates <-- templates for this app only
|-|-|-travello
|-|-|-|-template1.html
|-|-|-|-.......
|-|-.......
|-templates <- This is the templates folder for your site
|-|-homepage.html
|-|-..........
|-manage.py
|-requirements.txt
```

So in your case your templates folder is in your site configuration folder which is not a good practice. you have to move it one step higher.

**Good practices tips:**
At the root of your site (same level than manage.py) you have a templates folder which will contain the templates commons to all your applications.
In each application you have a folder templates/app_name which contain all the templates specifics for this application.

You have the same architecture for statics.

Answer (score 1):

Inside templates create another new directory by your app name `travello`  then keep the html file inside the `travello` directory

```
travello
| templates/travello/homepage.html
|-views.py
travellProj
|-urls.py
|-setting.py
```

Then `views` should be like

```
def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'travello/homepage.html')
```